# How to force action buttons to appear in same row in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

Action buttons are added to jqGrid columns using colmodel below.
Column width 45 is sufficient to hold both buttons in same row.
Edit and delete buttons appear in separate rows and row height in increased.
For unknown reason there is empty space before both buttons, there do not appear in left side in column.

If inline edit starts, save and cancel button also appear in separate rows.

How to force buttons to appear in same row witohut increasing column width ?

```
grid.jqGrid({
  colModel: [{name:_actions,width:45,
  formatter:"actions",
  formatoptions:
    {keys:true}
}, ....
```

**update**

Toolbar containts text right to button. Removing 30px from style creates overlapping buttons so I cannot remove it.

According to Oleg suggestion I added

```
.ui-inline-edit, .ui-inline-del, .ui-inline-save, .ui-inline-cancel
{
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

and

```
                colModel: [{"hidden":false,"label":" Muuda ","name":"_actions","width":($.browser.webkit == true? 58: 53)
,"align":"center","sortable":false,"formatter":"actions","formatoptions":{"keys":true,"delbutton":false,"onSuccess":function (jqXHR) {
actionresponse = jqXHR;
return true;
}
,"afterSave":function (rowID) {
cancelEditing($('#grid'));aftersavefunc(rowID,actionresponse)}
,"onError":errorfunc
,"extraparam":{"_dokdata":FormData
},"afterRestore":setFocusToGrid
,"onEdit":function (rowID) {
                            if (typeof (lastSelectedRow) !== 'undefined' && rowID !== lastSelectedRow)
                                       cancelEditing($('#grid'));
                           lastSelectedRow = rowID;
                                  }
}},
```

to style but this does not change anything, buttons still appear in two rows. How to fix ?

**Update 2**

adding fixed: true puts buttons to same row.
There are two issues:

Buttons are two small

Column contains only edit button ( delbutton:false option used).
Edit button width is small and icon is not centered.
How to increase edit button width to column width-few pixels  so that clicking anywhere in column starts edit mode and show edit icon in center of column ?
How to increase save ad cancle button widths so that both occupy 50%- few pixels  of action column width?

Multiple rapid clicks cause edit button so stop working

Save button appears in the same place as edit button and save to server takes some time.
If This place is clicked rapidly, inline edit mode is toggled before save is completed and autocomplete controls are
not created anymore.
after that edit button does not work at all.
How to prevent multiple save button clicks: disable save button or whole grid if clicked once or other solution and show "Saving..." message until save is completed?

style used:

```
td.ui-pg-button > div.ui-pg-div { margin-right: 30px }
```

colmodel:

```
colModel: [{
fixed:true,
label:" Change ",
name:"_actions",
width:($.browser.webkit == true? 58: 53)
,align:"center",
sortable:false,
formatter:"actions",
formatoptions:{"keys":true,"delbutton":false,
  "onSuccess":function (jqXHR) {actionresponse = jqXHR;return true;}
  ,"afterSave":function (rowID) {
      cancelEditing($('#grid'));aftersavefunc(rowID,actionresponse);actionresponse=null; }
  ,"onError":errorfunc
  ,"extraparam":{"_dokdata":FormData
  },
afterRestore:setFocusToGrid
,onEdit:function (rowID) {
     if (typeof (lastSelectedRow) !== 'undefined' && rowID !== lastSelectedRow)
        cancelEditing($('#grid'));
     lastSelectedRow = rowID;
   }
}}
```

Comment: In your demo (test case) which I use the setting are **still not included**. You should just trace the styles which you used or update you testcase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find 45px as the width for the column with the `formatter:"actions"` a little to small. It seems to my that 53px or 58px looks better. The calculation is the following: every button has 16px. Two buttons will be shown at once. The second button (Delete or Cancel) has `left-margin:5px`. Moreover all the buttons will be placed inside the div which has `margin-left: 8px;`. If you want to have the same margin at the right side of the second button the total width should be 8+16+5+16+8=53px. In case of usage of Webkit browser it should be 5px more because of other calculation of the column width (calculation will be without margin and padding which are 5px per default). So I would recommend you to use

```
width: ($.browser.webkit == true? 58: 53)
```

You main problem exist because of you set `margin-right:30px` of the `ui-pg-div` class **in your CSS**. I could see that only because you previously send me the URL of your demo page.

All actions buttons use `ui-pg-div` together with `ui-inline-edit`, `ui-inline-del`, ... for the actions buttons. So you have to: either to remove the setting `margin-right:30px` for the `ui-pg-div` class or overwrite the `margin-right` for `ui-inline-edit`, `ui-inline-del`, `ui-inline-save` and `ui-inline-cancel` with respect of `!important` additional attribute.

Comment: thank you. I implemented all your great suggestions but buttons still appear in 2 rows in IE and FireFox. I updated answer 2 times and provided code.

Comment: @Andrus: I suggest you to use `td.ui-pg-button > div.ui-pg-div { margin-right: 30px }` instead of `.ui-pg-div { margin-right: 30px }` which you use currently then the CSS setting will have no effect on the actions buttons.

Comment: thank you. I tried this setting and also removed ui-pg-div entirely. Buttons still appear in two rows. I updated style in testcase.

Comment: @Andrus: I see action buttons in **one row** in IE9 in your testcase. Moreover I could see that **you don't use `fixed:true` for the column** so your current `width:65` setting will be displayed on my monitor as `width: 47px;`. I recommend you to use `fixed: true, width: ($.browser.webkit == true? 58: 53)`

Comment: Thank you very much. Adding fixed: true puts buttons to same row. However there are two issues. I updated question and described them

Comment: @Andrus: I don't understand the first problem. You can just reduce the column width to 8+16+8=32 (or 32+5=37 for webkit browsers). The second problem should be analysed before. Today I probably don't find to do this.

Comment: thank you. The first problem is that I'm looking for a way to make buttons as wide as column width for touch screen and small resolution. User can specify column width and edititing action should start if clicked anywhere in cell. After that save and cancle button width should be 50% of cell width. I tried `"width":($.browser.webkit == true? 37: 32)` but in this case save and cancel buttons are displayed in separate rows like before. For second issue I can create testcase. It looks like event sequence issue

Comment: thank you. I updated testcase. Issues: rapid clicks in edit/save buttons cause errors "... input control not found",
clicking in start or end of action column cell is ignored (edit button width is too small), save/cancel buttons appear in separate rows

Comment: @Andrus: I could debug the problem and it seems to me that you should just remove the `alert` from `input_autocomplete` function. The situation is the following. `setTimeout` from the `combobox_element` was executed, but the body of the `setTimeout` could be run **after** the inline editing are saved. In the case the corresponding input field worked without `autocomplete`, but it is not a real problem. In the body of `setTimeout` the first statement (`$(newel).parent()...` do nothing because `newel` has now no parent. The `var input = $("input", newel)` is also empty and `input.length === 0`.

Comment: @Andrus: So everything is OK. You can consider to use `editformbutton: true` in case of the usage of `delbutton: false`. No "Cancel" button will be used and form editing instead of inline editing will be used.

Comment: thank you. Removing alert() seems to fix the issue. I prefer to have inline edit button also. `editformbutton:true` removes inline edit button so I cannot use it. In IE9 there are two IE only issues: a) pressing Save button does not disable jqgrid. b) Pressing edit button increases row height by 1-2 pixels causing annoying wrap in screen. How to fix those issues ? How to make edit button width same as actions column width so it can be cliked easily ?